# Making A Form That Adds To Links

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hyperlink

How Do I Create A Form That Adds Whatever Was In The Form To The End Of A Link?

For example:

When I enter "test" into the form, it takes you to http://example.com/item/test
Another example:
When I enter "hello" it takes me to http://dictionary.com/words?=hello
Is this possible? And if it is how do I do it? I want to integrate this into my site. Do I use Javascript or HTML?

Comment: Please reduce the use of upper-case letters in the title!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). The two examples you cite differ in that one uses a url query string, and the other does not. Which form do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, even tho not recommended, but since your question is not much specific of what you're wanting to (depending on the complexity of what you want to achieve), here it goes :

```
location.href = location.href += "&#47;" 
+= document.getElementById("YourInputIDHere").value;
```

Comment: I want to add a form on my website where you enter a model number and when you click submit, it takes you to the page.  (where it has information on the model)I am very new to these kinds of things. How would I make and put it in a html form?

Answer (score 1):

Try this function, the form value would be the param.

```
function addStringToEndOfLink(param){
    url = location.href;
    url += (url.split('?')[1] ? '/':'?') + param;
    return url;
}
```